# Ajax Listener called only on alternate selections of <p:selectOneMenu>

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish

I am building a dropdown by reading the database and then selecting the value for further processing. The problem occurs in the processing part.

The ajax listener for the dropdown gets triggered only on *alternate* selection and not on *every* selection. If I select a value for the first time, the listener does not trigger. If I select the second time it gets triggered again. The third time, again it doesn't trigger and so on.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectedBPZero" value="#{selectCriteriaBean.selectedBPZero}" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Select Option" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Add New BP" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectCriteriaBean.bpZeroList}"/>
    <p:ajax listener="#{selectCriteriaBean.bpZeroListSelectActionByAjaxCall}" event="change" update="selectedBPOne,selectedBPOneTextInfo" process="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Listener Method is as below

```
public void bpZeroListSelectActionByAjaxCall() {
    setParentBusinessProcessId(0);
    setSelectedBPOne(0);
    setSelectedBPTwo(0);

    setBPOneListRendered(false);
    setBPTwoListRendered(false);

    setModifyButtonBPZeroRendered(false);       
    setModifyButtonBPOneRendered(false);
    setModifyButtonBPTwoRendered(false);
    if (getSelectedBPZero() == 0) {
        RedirectScreen.redirectToPage("/ALM/home.faces");
    } else {
        if (getSelectedBPZero() == 1) {
            setAddBPLevelNumber(0);
            addBP();                            
        } else {
            setBPOneListRendered(true);
            setModifyButtonBPZeroRendered(true);
            // Get BP List
            bpLevelOneList = bpList(1,getSelectedBusinessProcessLevelZero());
            RedirectScreen.redirectToPage("/ALM/home.faces");       
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the event to `valueChange` and `click`, but it doesn't work. I am working on Eclipse with GlassFish setup.

The same code I tested in Rational Application Developer (RAD) and it is working there.

TIA

Comment: please post code of your listener method...

Comment: @Vrushank I have added the listener method in the question

Comment: Didn't find the solution but Now I know why it happened and changed the coding. I was using more than one bean in one page to split the functionality into different Managed Bean. But when I kept all the functionality into Single Managed Bean, I didn't face any problem. Thanks to everyone who read this and try to find the solution